# Update the price of a line item after shipping method is selected

Tags: commerce

I looked everywhere and couldn't find the appropriate and clear explanation of how to change the price of a line item.
I have a line item called "fee", the fee changes based on the date and zipcode. I have a function that returns the correct fee based on the parameters.
Now what hook do I call to update the "fee" line item?
This is what I found

```
function ck_custom_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper)
{
$fee = _ck_custom_delivery_fee($order);//this function returns an integer

foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper)
{
    if($line_item_wrapper->type->value()=="fee")
    {
        //I would like to update the fee 
    }
}
}
```

Please what is the right of way of accomplishing this?
FYI: I'm using the commerce fees module if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the price components of the line item you're wanting to update. You can use rules for this, but since you're writing a hook, you can just call the function that Rules would use:

```
commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount($line_item, $amount, $component_name, $round_mode);
```

For example, if you want to change it to $5.00:

```
commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount($line_item, 500, 'base', COMMERCE_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```